# Default DatePicker dialog layout config issue

Tags: android, android-layout, landscape, android-datepicker

[image: Landscape mode]

[image: potrait mode]

In landscape mode datepicker dialog is looking non-uniform "+" button size and "-" button size are differnt..

my xml layout is like this

```
 <DatePicker
         android:id="@+id/dialog"
       android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

why i am getting that non-uniformity in landscape mode? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its depending on your device screen size. That all device has different OS version of Android so getting different result for this dialog with orientation. If you want look common and interactive you need to implement by your style and size